How to check for activated automation
Is there a way to check for activated automation?
I want to extract it to DE:

Automation Name
Activation status
Last Execution Date


You can always consult the Automation Instance Data View
What This Data View Shows:

Automations that ran recently
When an automation ran
The duration of an automation
Whether an automation succeeded, skipped, or failed
The reason an automation failed
The file that was being processed when a triggered automation failed

No reason to add it to a DE, as you can always query the data view directly.

No immediate reason to add it to a DE - but I'd do that anyway. you'll actually see what you are working on, can control retention and could enable better performance / longer data availability :)

Agreed, @JonasLamberty - I just wanted to emphasize the availability of this data in a queryable form, rather than only e.g. through SOAP API

I want to extract a list of activated automations.

@youkey use SQL to query the data view, it will provide you this info. You probably want to filter by AutomationInstanceStatus field
